# Assistance needed for a google search of posts in a specified forum

Tags: google-search

This is my first post and I am hoping someone can help me out with my google search inquiry.

I am trying to search for a particular **user’s** post in a specified **sub-forum** that has generated 20 **likes** or more.

For example, I am trying to find **Isaac Jordan's** (not a real person btw) most **liked** posts in the **Crypto** sub-forum of the following site **www.rooshvforum.com**.

Here is an example of the exact type of post I am searching for [image]

The following string is the closest I could come up with. I know its incorrect but I just wanted to make an attempt at it:

```
site:rooshvforum.com “the following [>20] users like Isaac Jordan’s post”
```

Would be great to get some assistance on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with plain google search. A web-crawling solution might be better here, but I think this would slide too much into software-recommendation to be on-topic here.

Comment: surely there's a way to do this ?? Can you recommend me to any forum or site that might be able to help me please?

Answer (score 1):

try to paste this into your search bar:

```
site:rooshvforum.com "the following" "users like Isaac Jordan’s post"
```

[image]